# github upload distribute error url is not a valiad remote name

Tags: git, github, upload

I try to upload my new project to github.

the error is：

```
C:\workspace\helloboard>git push origin master
Username for 'https://github.com': thinksource
Password for 'https://thinksource@github.com':
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/thinksource、angularbigquery.git/': F
ailed connect to github.com:443; No error
```

and then I think the remote url may wrong, I want to change it:

```
C:\workspace\helloboard>git remote rename https://github.com/thinksource/angular
bigquery.git/ https://github.com/thinksource/angularbigquer.git
fatal: 'https://github.com/thinksource/angularbigquer.git' is not a valid remote
name
```

why the alreay exist .git is not valid remote name, what is valid name?

Comment: Try it without .git in the end ` https://github.com/thinksource/angularbigquer`

Comment: @khajvah I did the https://github.com/thinksource/angularbigquer then still same: fatal: 'https://github.com/thinksource/angularbigquer' is not a valid remote name

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you should find out which remote you have to rename.

```
git remote -v
```

Then

```
git remote set-url remotename newgiturl.git
```